# removing STATS_PERSISTENT=0 for innodb

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

Is it okay to disable "STATS_PERSISTENT=0" from mariadb 10.0 dump, restoring to mariadb 5.5

ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin STATS_PERSISTENT=0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STATS_PERSISTENT parameter appeared in MariaDB 10.0 (and MySQL 5.6) so any MariaDB/MySQL version before that won't recognise it.

If you are restoring a table with STATS_PERSISTENT parameter to MariaDB 5.5, you will have to remove this parameter.

It is safe to do so, because statistics are not stored in the table itself, so your data won't be affected.

If you want to know more about InnoDB persistent statistics read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html) doc.